# Is it true that C only allows for up to 6 variables in scope at any time?

Tags: c, scope

I'm trying to find a list of rules pertaining to how C handles statically scoped integer variables but can't find anything online, or I'm not looking in the right place.  One search result stated that in C, statically scoped variables are limited to at most 6 variables in scope at any time during execution of the code.   Is this true?

Comment: Uh, no. I would stay far away from whatever is saying that

Comment: See the Translation Limits section here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier

Comment: Could you share the URL where you read that statement?

Comment: There is no such thing as “statically scoped” in C. The C scopes are function, file, block, and function prototype. C also has storage durations, which are static, thread, automatic, and allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Per the [C 2017 online draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf#page22), section 5.2.4.1, you can have up to 4095 external identifiers in a translation unit (static variable names, function names, etc.).

I'm assuming that's what you mean by "statically scoped", anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not, because I count seven local variables.

```c
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
  int d = 4;
  int e = 5;
  int f = 6;
  int g = 7;

  printf("%d\n", a + b + c + d + e + f + g);
}

int main(void) {
  foo();
}

$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
28
```

Still no issues.

```c
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
  static int a = 1;
  static int b = 2;
  static int c = 3;
  static int d = 4;
  static int e = 5;
  static int f = 6;
  static int g = 7;

  printf("%d\n", a + b + c + d + e + f + g);
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
}

$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
28
```